# need to validate the times but keep running into issues

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, boolean

I am new to java and I am trying to figure out how to get the user input of time validated. If the user inputs a number lower then 800 or a number higher then 1900 the they should get the proper error message. I also want the user to get an error message if they input a time like 860 etc... I've been wrapped around this part for too long and I definitely need help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FugonIsaac06 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {


  boolean keepAsking = true;


  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);


  String userInput = "";
  int input_Start = 0;
  int input_End = 0;



  while (keepAsking) {

   System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
   userInput = reader.nextLine();
   if (userInput.length() >= 3) {

    keepAsking = false;

   } else {
    System.out.println("Name must be at least 3 characters long.");

   }

  }
  keepAsking = true;
  //You will need to somehow separate the hours and minutes from the input.
  //Use integer division and modulus to separate hours and minutes.
  //Hours = Input / 100
  //Minutes = Input % 100
  //To convert the minutes to parts of an hour divide the minutes by 60.0.
  //Parts of an hour = Minutes / 60.0
  int hours_Start = input_Start / 100;
  int minutes_Start = input_Start % 100;
  while (keepAsking) {
   System.out.print("Enter start time: ");
   input_Start = reader.nextInt();
   if ((input_Start > hours_Start) &&
    (input_Start < minutes_Start)) {
    keepAsking = true;



    System.out.println("Start time should be between 800 and 1900");


   } else {


    System.out.println("Time is malformed, minutes should be between 0 and 59");
   }

  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor your code to something like this:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String username = "";

do {
    username = reader.nextLine();
} while(username.length() < 3);

int timeStart;
String timestamp = "";

// enter a timestamp in the form of hoursminutes
// hours = 0 (or 00) to 23
// minutes = 0 (or 00) to 59
do {
    timestamp = reader.nextLine();
} while(!timestamp.matches("(?:2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9])[0-5][0-9]"));

// parse out the hours and minutes components
int hours = Integer.parseInt(timeStart) / 100;
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeStart) % 100;
```

Using `do` loops works well for your use case, because you want to eagerly accept an initial user input, regardless of any previous state, yet you want to have the ability to loop back again should validation fail.  The `while` conditions validate the input, checking that a username have 3 or more characters, and that the time start is within the range you specified.

Comment: What about if the user inputs a time like 863? Do I use another do loop? Also thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code try it

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Demo {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  boolean keepAsking = true;
  Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
  String userInput = "";
  int input_hours =0;
  int input_End = 0;
  String time;

  while (keepAsking) {
   System.out.print("Please enter your name: ");
   userInput = reader.nextLine();
   if (userInput.length() >= 3) {
    break;
   // keepAsking = false;
   } else {
    System.out.println("Name must be at least 3 characters long.");
   }
  }
  keepAsking = true;


  //You will need to somehow separate the hours and minutes from the input.
  //Use integer division and modulus to separate hours and minutes.
  //Hours = Input / 100
  //Minutes = Input % 100
  //To convert the minutes to parts of an hour divide the minutes by 60.0.
  //Parts of an hour = Minutes / 60.0
  int hours_Start = 0;
  int minutes_Start = 0;
  while (keepAsking) {
   System.out.print("Enter start time HH:MM : ");   
   time = reader.next();   
   String []timeArr = time.split(":");   
    input_hours =   Integer.parseInt(timeArr[0]);   
    minutes_Start =  Integer.parseInt(timeArr[1]);     

   if (input_hours > 19 || input_hours <  8) {
    keepAsking = true;
    System.out.println("Start time should be between 800 and 1900");
   } else if(minutes_Start<0 || minutes_Start>59){


    System.out.println("Time is malformed, minutes should be between 0 and 59");
   }else{
       System.out.println("You have entered correct time");
    break;   
    }

  }
 }
}
```

[image]